# Logfile processing: shorten long hex strings

Tags: logging, awk, sed, replace

I have a logfile which is hard to read because of long hex strings (hashes, signatures) and am looking for a way to replace those strings with a shortened version.

Example:

```
$ cat sample_line
2018-04-17 13:08:03  IO Worker #2 TRACE engine  Handling a valid ConsensusMessage { vote_step: VoteStep { height: 1, view: 1, step: Precommit }, block_hash: Some(c70cd816cd441fda978f6302739892c0877349901c71f1bc9e637159b47989a7), signature: dfc14c535a9cddd861d640310a9d94252aa7d67c330a218312705d26c0d8b8d1670976566754033798d08b6c484470af18e985420f9048c782cd61ea212d416500 }
```

I tried with `sed` and managed to shorten the signature:

```
$ cat sample_line | sed 's/signature: \(.\{6\}\)\w* \(.*\)/signature: \1…\2/'
2018-04-17 13:08:03  IO Worker #2 TRACE engine  Handling a valid ConsensusMessage { vote_step: VoteStep { height: 1, view: 1, step: Precommit }, block_hash: Some(c70cd816cd441fda978f6302739892c0877349901c71f1bc9e637159b47989a7), signature: dfc14c…}
```

However this isn't a very satisfying solution as it's not very generic.

**What I want:**
A command which replaces any hex string with a min. length of say 32 chars with its leading 6 chars plus an ellipsis. For the given example:

```
2018-04-17 13:08:03  IO Worker #2 TRACE engine  Handling a valid ConsensusMessage { vote_step: VoteStep { height: 1, view: 1, step: Precommit }, block_hash: Some(c70cd8…), signature: dfc14c… }
```

It would even suffice to shorten any string with a min. length (as there's no other long strings in that log anyway).

I suspect that other tools (awk) are better suited for the task.

Comment: [edit] your question to show the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed`. Just get the 1st initial 6 hex characters into a capturing group and ignore the rest hexadecimal characters.

```
$ cat sample_line 
2018-04-17 13:08:03  IO Worker #2 TRACE engine  Handling a valid ConsensusMessage { vote_step: VoteStep { height: 1, view: 1, step: Precommit }, block_hash: Some(c70cd816cd441fda978f6302739892c0877349901c71f1bc9e637159b47989a7), signature: dfc14c535a9cddd861d640310a9d94252aa7d67c330a218312705d26c0d8b8d1670976566754033798d08b6c484470af18e985420f9048c782cd61ea212d416500 }
$ sed -r 's/([a-f0-9]{6})[a-f0-9]+/\1.../g' sample_line 
2018-04-17 13:08:03  IO Worker #2 TRACE engine  Handling a valid ConsensusMessage { vote_step: VoteStep { height: 1, view: 1, step: Precommit }, block_hash: Some(c70cd8...), signature: dfc14c... }
```